# window is not defined Nuxt for vue-slick

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, slick.js

Hello I am having an issue with Nuxts ssr. I a trying to add 'vue-slick' to my web app and no matter what I do it continues to show "window is not defined".

As you can see I have tried multiple ways to allow vue-slick to be loaded on client side. Using plugins didn't help, using process.client in my component did not work as well.

Components/Carousel/Carousel.vue

```
 <template>
<div class="carousel">
<Slick ref="slick" :options="slickOptions">
    <a href="http://placehold.it/320x120">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x120" alt="">
        </a>
        ...
    <a href="http://placehold.it/420x220">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/420x220" alt="">
        </a>


    </Slick>
</div>

</template>

<script>
if (process.client) {
  require('vue-slick')
}
import Slick from 'vue-slick'

export default {    

    components: {
        Slick
    },
    data() {
        return {

            slickOptions: {
                        slidesToShow: 4

            },

            isMounted: false
        }
    },

    methods: {

    }


}
</script>
```

nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-slick', ssr: false }
  ],
```

plugins/vue-slick

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSlick from 'vue-slick'

Vue.use(VueSlick);
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this is due to nuxt trying to render the slick component on the server side, even though you have set `ssr: false` in nuxt.config.

I have had this issue in other nuxt plugins and these steps should fix it.

in nuxt.config.js add this to your build object:

```
build: {
    extend(config, ctx) {
    if (ctx.isServer) {
        config.externals = [
          nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^vue-slick/]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

and in the page where you are trying to serve it you have to not mount the component until the page is fully mounted. So in your Components/Carousel/Carousel.vue set it up like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="carousel">
    <component
      :is="slickComp"
      ref="slick" 
      :options="slickOptions"
    >
      <a href="http://placehold.it/320x120">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x120" alt="">
      </a>
        ...
      <a href="http://placehold.it/420x220">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/420x220" alt="">
      </a>
    </component>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then in your script section import your component and declare it like this:

```
<script> 
  export default {
    data: () => ({
        'slickComp': '',
    }),
    components: {
        Slick: () => import('vue-slick')
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
           this.slickComp = 'Slick'
        })
    },
  }
</script>
```

Bascially this means the component isn't declared until the mounted function is called which is after all the server side rendering. And that should do it. Good luck.

Comment: Thats amazing! thank you for the help you are a life saver!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. If you are happy with the answer please mark it as correct.

Comment: I highly appreciate the help but all of a sudden my app is saying "nodeExternals" is not defined from the nuxt.config.js. I was wondering if you ever came across this?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. Add this line `const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')` at the top of your nuxt.config.js. Above the module exports, there will be a const pkg... and just paste it after that.

Answer (score 1):

I found another simple solution.
simply install "vue-slick" package to your nuxt project.
$ yarn add vue-slick

then component markup like below.

```
<template>
    <component :is="slick" :options="slickOptions">
      <div>Test1</div>
      <div>Test2</div>
      <div>Test3</div>
    </component>
</template>
```

Finally set data and computed properties like this.

```
data() {
    return {
      slickOptions: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
     slick() {
       return () => {
          if (process.client) {
          return import("vue-slick");
          }
        };
      },
    },
```

This solution prevents slick component importing globally as a plugin in nuxt config.